# C++ CLI KeyDown::raise Error error C3767 candidate function(s) not accessible

Tags: winforms, events, event-handling, compiler-errors, c++-cli

I have a scenario with three entities:

- An interface with one method stub
- A class that inherits from `System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow` and implements the interface
- A wrapper class that has a private member of the class type and a public property of the interface type. This class also has a `KeyDown` event member that's to be invoked/raised from the window class

These are the files I'm using:

*INativeWindow.h*

```
#pragma  once
public interface class INativeWindow
{
    void Nothing();
};
```

*CLINativeWindow.h*

```
#pragma  once
ref class NWHolder;
public ref class CLINativeWindow : System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow, INativeWindow
{
public:
    NWHolder^ Parent;
    virtual void  Nothing() sealed;
    void DoIt();
};
```

*CLINativeWindow.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CLINativeWindow.h"

void CLINativeWindow::Nothing()
{
    Console::Write("None");
}
void CLINativeWindow::DoIt()
{
    Parent->KeyDown(this, nullptr);
};
```

*NWHolder.h*

```
#pragma  once
#include "INativeWindow.h"
#include "CLINativeWindow.h"

public ref class NWHolder
{

internal:
    event System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler^ KeyDown;
public:
    virtual property INativeWindow^ OwnNativeWindow
    {
        INativeWindow^ __clrcall get() sealed;
        void __clrcall set(INativeWindow^ value) sealed; 
    }

private:
    CLINativeWindow^ nativeWindow_;
};
```

*NWHolder.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "NWHolder.h"


INativeWindow^ NWHolder::OwnNativeWindow::get()
{
    return nativeWindow_;
}

void NWHolder::OwnNativeWindow::set(INativeWindow^ value)
{
    nativeWindow_ = dynamic_cast<CLINativeWindow^>(value); 
}
```

At **compile** time, I get this error:
`Error  1 error C3767: 'NWHolder::KeyDown::raise': candidate function(s) not accessible ..\NativeWindows\CLINativeWindow.cpp    10`

Is there anything that can be done? I tried even `#pragma make_public(System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler)` but it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'raise' inner method of a C++/CLI event is always declared protected. Add a method on NWHolder named "FireKeyDownEvent", and give it whatever accessibility you like.